# That would be great if you have one or That would be great if you had one?

Tags: conditional-constructions

Which one is correct?

> That would be great if you **have** one

or

> That would be great if you **had** one?

Comment: What is your own opinion?

Comment: Both could be correct and idiomatic under the proper circumstances.

Answer (score 2):

> Ah, my pen's out of ink!
>   --I could lend you mine.
>   That would be great, if you have one.  Thanks.

or

> If I had a boat we could take it across the lake to a great fishing spot I discovered.
>   -- That would be great, if you had one. We're not catching anything here.